# "Please send me your most lucrative offer." Is that correct?

Tags: word-usage

Lucrative is defined as

> adj. producing a great deal of profit.

In the context, the speaker is negotiating with the listener and asking for the best possible price for something, which he intends to buy. Is it correct to ask for the "most lucrative offer"?

Comment: Lucrative has a connotation of somewhat dodgy, and definitely not good for the seller. 'Best' would be better I think.

Comment: @Deonyi On the other hand, you would love to receive a "lucrative job offer", wouldn't you?

Comment: "Lucrative" is not usually applied to a job offer; it usually refers to profit on a transaction.

Comment: Lucrative for whom?

Comment: Exactly! @Mick - one's profit will be the other's loss!

Comment: Just say "Please send me your best offer."

Comment: Buyers don't normally ask for the price associated with the biggest profit margin. But it may well be 'correct' for a particular buyer in a particular setting - e.g. when they want to be generous to the seller. Please clarify what kind of 'correctness' you're after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Lucrative" is something that happens later, after the transaction.  You could make a deal, which could then go on to be lucrative for you, but at the time of the deal, that is in the future and thus unknown.

Looking back, we could say "That deal turned out to be very lucrative", but at the time of the deal it's not appropriate as it hasn't happened yet.

Lucrative also has a connotation that the seller is making a mistake in selling it, or in making the deal:  if it's going to be "lucrative" then that suggests they should hang on to it rather than sell it.

In the present tense, ie at the time of the deal itself, a better word to use would be "most attractive", or more simply "best".